# http3 removes domain from all links

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, fastcgi, quic, http3

So couple days ago I installed NGINX 1.23.3 QUIC with Brotli, TLS 1.3, OpenSSL 1.1.1s with HTTP/2 and HTTP/3... so server with fastcgi and php-fpm... when I load site for first time it works with http2 and everything is fine. After reload page, or I visit on site some article or category there is no more domain.com in links... for example https: //example.com/somecat/subcat... with http3 is https ://somecat/subcat... a lot of hours I was trying to find problem but nothing, even cant imagine where to look.

Only what I figured out is that if i put proxy_pass http: //example.com; after location / { it fixes problem only for main page but not all around site (categories...etc.). Maybe somebody had this kind of problem... Any advise would be great!!!

**Host config looks like:**

```
server {
    listen      IP:443 http3;
    listen      IP:443 ssl http2;
    server_name www.example.com;
    return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
    ssl_certificate      /home/admin/conf/web/ssl.example.com.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key  /home/admin/conf/web/ssl.example.com.key;
    }

server {
    listen      IP:443 http3 reuseport;
    listen      IP:443 ssl http2;
    server_name example.com;
    root        /home/admin/web/example.com/public_html;
    index       index.php index.html index.htm;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/domains/example.com.log combined;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/domains/example.com.bytes bytes;
    access_log  off;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/domains/example.com.error.log error;


    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    quic_retry on;
    ssl_early_data on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
    ssl_ciphers TLS13-CHACHA20-POLY1305-SHA256:TLS13-AES-128-GCM-SHA256:TLS13-AES-256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE:!COMPLEMENTOFDEFAULT;
    #ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
    ssl_ecdh_curve X25519:prime256v1:secp384r1;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;
    ssl_session_tickets off;
    ssl_buffer_size 8k;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=300s;
    resolver_timeout 5s;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt;


    ssl_certificate      /home/admin/conf/web/ssl.example.com.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key  /home/admin/conf/web/ssl.example.com.key;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload";
    http2_push_preload on;

    add_header Alt-Svc 'h3=":443"; ma=86400, h3-29=":443"; ma=86400';
    add_header QUIC-Status $http3;

    include /etc/nginx/badbots.conf;

    location / {


        rewrite "^/pm(/(.*))?/?$" /index.php?do=pm last;
        rewrite "^/friends/([^/]*)(/?)+$" /index.php?do=friends&user=$1 last;
        rewrite "^/friends/([^/]*)/page/([0-9]+)(/?)+$" /index.php?do=friends&user=$1&cstart=$2 last;
        rewrite "^/friends/([^/]*)/common(/?)+$" /index.php?do=friends&subaction=common&user=$1 last;
        rewrite "^/friends/([^/]*)/common/page/([0-9]+)(/?)+$" /index.php?do=friends&subaction=common&user=$1&cstart=$2 last;
        rewrite "^/friends/([^/]*)/requests(/?)+$" /index.php?do=friends&subaction=requests&user=$1 last;
        rewrite "^/friends/([^/]*)/requests/page/([0-9]+)(/?)+$" /index.php?do=friends&subaction=requests&user=$1&cstart=$2 last;
        rewrite "^/friends/([^/]*)/suggestions(/?)+$" /index.php?do=friends&subaction=suggestions&user=$1 last;
        rewrite "^/page/([0-9]+)(/?)$" /index.php?cstart=$1 last;
        rewrite "^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/page,([0-9]+),([0-9]+),(.*).html$" /index.php?subaction=showfull&year=$1&month=$2&day=$3&news_page=$4&cstart=$5&news_name=$6&seourl=$6 last;
        rewrite "^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/page,([0-9]+),(.*).html$" /index.php?subaction=showfull&year=$1&month=$2&day=$3&news_page=$4&news_name=$5&seourl=$5 last;
        rewrite "^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/print:page,([0-9]+),(.*).html$" /index.php?mod=print&subaction=showfull&year=$1&month=$2&day=$3&news_page=$4&news_name=$5&seourl=$5 last;
        rewrite "^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/(.*).html$" /index.php?subaction=showfull&year=$1&month=$2&day=$3&news_name=$4&seourl=$4 last;
        rewrite "^/([^.]+)/page,([0-9]+),([0-9]+),([0-9]+)-(.*).html$" /index.php?newsid=$4&news_page=$2&cstart=$3&seourl=$5&seocat=$1 last;
        rewrite "^/([^.]+)/page,([0-9]+),([0-9]+)-(.*).html$" /index.php?newsid=$3&news_page=$2&seourl=$4&seocat=$1 last;
        rewrite "^/([^.]+)/print:page,([0-9]+),([0-9]+)-(.*).html$" /index.php?mod=print&news_page=$2&newsid=$3&seourl=$4&seocat=$1 last;
        rewrite "^/([^.]+)/([0-9]+)-(.*).html$" /index.php?newsid=$2&seourl=$3&seocat=$1 last;


        location ~* ^.+\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif|bmp|ico|svg|css|js|woff|woff2|webp)$ {
            expires     max;
        }

        location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
                return  404;
            }

            fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php-example.com.sock;
            fastcgi_index   index.php;
            include         /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        }
    }

    error_page  403 /error/404.html;
    error_page  404 /error/404.html;
    error_page  500 502 503 504 /error/50x.html;

    location /error/ {
        alias   /home/admin/web/example.com/document_errors/;
    }

    location ~* "/\.(htaccess|htpasswd)$" {
        deny    all;
        return  404;
    }

    location /vstats/ {
        alias   /home/admin/web/example.com/stats/;
        include /home/admin/conf/web/example.com.auth*;
    }

    include     /etc/nginx/conf.d/phpmyadmin.inc*;
    include     /etc/nginx/conf.d/phppgadmin.inc*;
    include     /etc/nginx/conf.d/webmail.inc*;

    include     /home/admin/conf/web/snginx.example.com.conf*;

    location ~ "/uploads/.*\.php$|/templates/.*\.php$|/language/.*\.php$|/images/.*\.php$"
    {
        return 403;
    }
    location ~* (uploads|uploads/fotos|templates|language)/.+\.php {
        deny all;
    }
    location ~* /templates/.+\.tpl {
        deny all;
    }
    location ~* (engine/cache|engine/data) {
        deny all;
    }
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

**Nginx config:**

```
# Server globals
user                    nginx;
worker_processes        auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile    65535;
error_log               /var/log/nginx/error.log crit;
pid                     /var/run/nginx.pid;


# Worker config
events {
        worker_connections  1024;
        use                 epoll;
        multi_accept        on;
}


http {
    # Main settings
    sendfile                        on;
    #tcp_nopush                      on;
    #tcp_nodelay                     on;
    client_header_timeout           1m;
    client_body_timeout             1m;
    client_header_buffer_size       2k;
    client_body_buffer_size         256k;
    client_max_body_size            256m;
    large_client_header_buffers     4   8k;
    send_timeout                    30;
    keepalive_timeout               60 60;
    reset_timedout_connection       on;
    server_tokens                   off;
    server_name_in_redirect         off;
    types_hash_max_size             2048;
    variables_hash_max_size         1024;
    variables_hash_bucket_size      128;


    # Log format
    log_format  main    '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] $request '
                        '"$status" $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                        '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    log_format  bytes   '$body_bytes_sent';
    #access_log          /var/log/nginx/access.log main;
    access_log off;


    # Mime settings
    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;


    # Compression
    gzip                on;
    gzip_vary       on;
    gzip_comp_level     6;
    gzip_min_length     512;
    gzip_buffers        8 64k;
    gzip_proxied        any;
    gzip_disable        "MSIE [1-6]\.";
    gzip_types          text/plain text/css text/javascript text/js text/xml application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript application/xml application/xml+rss application/x-font-ttf image/svg+xml font/opentype text/x-component text/x-cross-domain-policy;


    # Proxy settings
    proxy_redirect      off;
    proxy_set_header    Host            $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass_header   Set-Cookie;
    proxy_connect_timeout   90;
    proxy_send_timeout  90;
    proxy_read_timeout  90;
    proxy_buffers       32 4k;


    # SSL PCI Compliance
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_ciphers TLS13-CHACHA20-POLY1305-SHA256:TLS13-AES-128-GCM-SHA256:TLS13-AES-256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE:!COMPLEMENTOFDEFAULT;


    # Error pages
    error_page          403          /error/403.html;
    error_page          404          /error/404.html;
    error_page          502 503 504  /error/50x.html;


    # Cache settings
    proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=2 keys_zone=cache:10m inactive=60m max_size=1024m;
    proxy_cache_key "$host$request_uri $cookie_user";
    proxy_temp_path  /var/cache/nginx/temp;
    proxy_ignore_headers Expires Cache-Control;
    proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout invalid_header http_502;
    proxy_cache_valid any 1d;


    # FastCgi Cache
    fastcgi_buffers 8 256k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 256k;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    fastcgi_cache_path /tmp/nginx_cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=fastcgicache:10m max_size=1024m inactive=1h;


    # File cache settings
    open_file_cache          max=10000 inactive=30s;
    open_file_cache_valid    60s;
    open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
    open_file_cache_errors   off;


    # Wildcard include
    include             /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

  
}
```

Comment: As far as I know, there is no stable release of nginx with QUIC support available. Therefore the question is off-topic here. You might get some help from nginx developer mailing list: https://mailman.nginx.org/mailman3/lists/nginx-devel.nginx.org/

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

Saved the file with the content ... noticed that HTTP_HOST disappears when loading http3, respectively, added it to the host fastcgi_param HTTP_HOST example.com; And everything works as it should! Happy as an elephant)))

p.s. How much correct is this line when loading http3 'HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL' => 'max-age=0', ???

Comment: https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?21,296365,296397#msg-296397

Answer (score 0):

There's a known backward compatibility break in `nginx-quic`: https://github.com/nginx-quic/nginx-quic/issues/3

For me I'm using

```
fastcgi_param HTTP_HOST $host;
```

to allow php server get the valid host from [`:authority`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70502726/what-is-the-purpose-of-http2-pseudo-headers-authority-method) pseudo-header, and replace all usages of [`$http_host`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_http_) with [`$host`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_host) in nginx config files: https://github.com/vstoykovbg/nginx.conf-examples/pull/2